# Python 3 quest command, IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x, quest

```
    def register():
    print("Register")
login = input("Enter login")
passwd = input("Enter password")
passwdacc = input("Accept password")
if passwdacc = passwd:
    print("You have registered, now please sign up")
else:
    print("Try again, passwords dont matches")
login2 = input("Enter login")
password = input("Enter password")
if password = passwd and login2 = login
    print("Accepted")
else:
    print("Try again")
```

sign_up()

Error(s), warning(s):

File "source_file.py", line 3
    login = input("Enter login")
                               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: I believe you should read about **indentation**.

Comment: Remember: `=` ≠ `==`

Comment: There are many things wrong with the code, and no actual question asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from wrong indentation, in conditional statements you need to replace assignment operators with comparison operators. Also, a `:` is missing from an `if statement`.

```
def register():
    print("Register")
    login = input("Enter login")
    passwd = input("Enter password")
    passwdacc = input("Accept password")

    if passwdacc == passwd:
        print("You have registered, now please sign up")
    else:
        print("Try again, passwords don't match")

    login2 = input("Enter login")
    password = input("Enter password")

    if password == passwd and login2 == login:
        print("Accepted")
    else:
        print("Try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def register():
        print("Register")
        login = input("Enter login")
        passwd = input("Enter password")
        passwdacc = input("Accept password")
        if passwdacc = passwd:
            print("You have registered, now please sign up")
        else:
            print("Try again, passwords dont matches")
        login2 = input("Enter login")
        password = input("Enter password")
        if password = passwd and login2 = login
            print("Accepted")
        else:
            print("Try again")
```

Comment: Please edit to include a comment explaining this code for the benefit of others.